# how to use jaxws for a class referencing an interface

Tags: interface, jax-ws

I have a java class which I need to annotate up for a web service. Everything is set up and compiles etc, the wsdl is generated using the maven plugin for wsprovide... the problem I have is that the class references an interface...

```
@WebService(name = "myWebService", targetNamespace = "......")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)

public class MyClassImpl implements MyClass {
protected TheService m_theService;
/**
 * @return the theService
 */
public TheService getTheService() {
    return m_theService;
}
```

TheService is an interface, and so I get a JAXB error... TheService is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.  The getTheService method does not need to be exposed in the web service, but I can't see how to get around it.  Can anyone explain what to do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Found this shortly after posting this message and managed to resolve my issues :-)

https://jaxb.dev.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate any method that does not require to be exposed with:

```
@WebMethod(exclude = true)
```

This way wsgen will ignore the method when generating the JAX-WS artifacts.